# How can I rearrange a menu link programmatically?

Tags: 8, testing

I created *Menu Link Content* entities and saved them in a menu.

```
$menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Menu item',
  'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
  'link' => [['uri' => 'internal:/']],
  'menu_name' => 'testing',
])->save();

$menu_link_2 = MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Menu item',
  'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
  'link' => [['uri' => 'internal:/']],
  'menu_name' => 'testing',
])->save();
```

How can I rearrange `$menu_link_2` to be a child of `$menu_link`?

Looking at `menu_ui`, they seem to update *Menu Link Content* in a given order, and then rebuild the menu tree; finally, the *Menu* entity is saved.

```
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_link_manager->updateDefinition($menu_link_2->getPluginId(), [
  'parent' => $menu_link->getPluginId(),
]);
```

How can I rebuild the menu tree and save the menu?

*Why?* I'm writing a Kernel test for a module that fires when the menu link content has been saved AND then when the Menu itself has been saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange a custom menu link when you set the 'weight' of the menu. See below code.

```
$menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Menu item',
  'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
  'link' => [['uri' => 'internal:/']],
  'menu_name' => 'testing',
  'weight' => 0,
])->save();
```

$menu_link_2 = MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Menu item',
  'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
  'link' => [['uri' => 'internal:/']],
  'menu_name' => 'testing',
  'weight' => 0,
])->save();

Comment: that's not what he's asking for, it's about nesting, not the weight

Comment: yes and no. In the title its about sorting. I came here for sorting an this is just what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Some nice helpers for rearranging existing menus programmatically.
https://www.drupal.org/project/codit_menu_tools